Replacement for IDurableActivityContext in isolated mode
Hi，Does anybody knows what is the replacement method for IDurableActivityContext in isolated mode If I want to pass the instant id from the "TaskOrchestrationContext"?
say in the previously in process method the OrchestratorFunction is like
public async Task<Result> ProcessFileAsync(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var fileName = context.GetInput<string>();

    try
    {   
        // Read the file.
        var readFileOperation = await context.CallActivityAsync<Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>>(ReadRecordsFromFileActivityFunction, fileName);
        if (!readFileOperation.Status)
        {
            if (!context.IsReplaying)
            {
                _logger.Warning("Cannot continue processing the file because the file reading operation failed.");
            }

            await MoveBlobAsync(context, _inputContainer, _errorContainer, fileName);

            return Result.Failure("Cannot continue processing the file because the file reading operation failed.");
        }

And in the ActivityFunction is
[FunctionName(nameof(ReadRecordsFromFileActivityFunction))]
public async Task<Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>> ReadFileAsync([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
{
    var fileName = context.GetInput<string>();

    var operation = await _blobReaderService.GetRecordsAsync(fileName);
    if (!operation.Status)
    {
        return Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>.Failure(operation.ErrorMessage);
    }

    var records = operation.Data;
    if (records == null || !records.Any())
    {
        _logger.Warning("There are no records.");
        return Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>.Failure("There are no records.");
    }

    // Set the main orchestration id.
    var orchestrationId = context.InstanceId;
    records.ForEach(x=>x.MainOrchestrationId = orchestrationId);

    return Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>.Success(records);
}

I can use IDurableActivityContext to get the context.InstanceId from OrchestratorFunction. But since the IDurableActivityContext has no longer exist is there a proper way we can get instant id from  OrchestratorFunction or we need to customized it? Like for this one what I can think is create an tuple something like in OrchestratorFunction
public async Task<Result> ProcessFileAsync(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var fileName = context.GetInput<string>();
    var instanceId = context.InstanceId;

    try
    {   
        // Read the file.
        var readFileOperation = await context.CallActivityAsync<Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>>(ReadRecordsFromFileActivityFunction, (fileName, instanceId));

And in ActivityFunction like :
[Function(nameof(ReadRecordsFromFileActivityFunction))]
public async Task<Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>> ReadFileAsync([ActivityTrigger] (string FileName, string InstanceId) parameters)
{
    var (fileName, instanceId) = parameters;
    var operation = await _blobReaderService.GetRecordsAsync(fileName);
    if (!operation.Status)
    {
        return Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>.Failure(operation.ErrorMessage);
    }

    var records = operation.Data;
    if (records == null || !records.Any())
    {
        _logger.Warning("There are no records.");
        return Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>.Failure("There are no records.");
    }

    
    records.ForEach(x=>x.MainOrchestrationId = instanceId);

    return Result<List<SmsRecipientFileModel>>.Success(records);
}

Is it the correct way to do it?

I just wondered why you need the instanceId at all? It sounds like you're using that to get around a different problem that might be solved a better way. Also, your Orchestration awaits a method called MoveBlobAsync - be aware that you cannot do I/O operations in an Orchestration, so you need to call another Activity for doing that blob move.

Hi Andrew thanks for the reply.MoveBlobAsync is not performing the I/O operation directly, actually what it does is to call an activity function that handles the blob movement. InstanceId in my view is essential for tracking propose like when reading file, storing data, error occurs. is used to have built in method context.InstanceId to get unique id from the Orchestration function, but seems it not doing it anymore in isolate .net8 version

I think if you're just using it for tracking errors then it might be better to think about throwing Exceptions (based on some strategy of your choosing). And in terms of knowing which orchestration stored which file, I'm not sure I understand why. Maybe you could explain more of this in your question - I still think there are likely to be better ways of achieving it?
